# Reference DLL project from a different solution in VS Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2019

I have seen similar questions, but the solutions seem to be deprecated or not compatible with VS Studio 2019.
Basically, I am building a client and a server application. I am building each one in a separate solution.
In the client solution, I added a Class Library project, which includes some classes I'll need to use in the server solution.

So, I right clicked on References in my solution explorer, and tried to find the solution. I browsed to the supposed location of the DLL in the first solution, but the problem is that there doesn't seem to be any .DLL file despite the project being a "Class Library (dll)". The only file is ClassName.csproj and I can't add that one. I also can't manually add the .cs files since it says its not a dll.

Comment: Why don't you add the project for the DLL to the server solution? (and then reference the project)

Comment: Use File > Add > Existing Project.  Having a project in more than one solution is not a problem.

Comment: Perhaps for this specific project it isn't, but supposing it's a very big app, wouldn't that be a bad practice since you'd essentially be repeating code unnecessarily? Also, why am I not able to add the class library of the other project? I thought that was the whole purpose of a class library, to be easily referenced.

Comment: You are not repeating anything if you add _the project_ to your server solution.

Comment: There just happens to be documentation on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019#projects-tab

Comment: A possible solution is to create a local nuget package this way you just need to update the package version in the solution using your library.

Comment: Did you build the `Class Library` first? And then add its dll from path `ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug`.